# How to send props to a component while using Route to load?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

1) If I am importing a component, I can send props to component like this,

```
<ImportedComponent props={props} />
```

Is there any way to send props to a component, If I am using Route?

```
<Route path={"...somePath"} component= {someComponent} />
```

2) Also, If I am in the required path already, Is there any difference in using

```
<Route />
```

to load a component and directly referring imported component this way,

```
<ImportedComponent />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render`

```
<Route
    path={"...somePath"}
    render={(props) => (<someComponent {...props} otherProps={otherProps} />)}
/>
```

Comment: parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text.

Comment: sorry I missed out curly braces for render. try it again.